# How to call a website from pc using a non registered domain name?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, ping

Usually When you ping a website (e.g Google.com) it replies with a specific Ip
My question is: Is there anyway where you can call a website and replies with an IP you have set manaually like 1.2.3.4

meaning if I ping google.com from my pc it will reply with 1.2.3.4

Comment: As written, I interpret it as: it seems like you are trying to fake/redirect a domain name - e.g. have google.com go to a different IP. If you are only doing this on your PC then you can add google.com and the fake IP (1.2.3.4) to your hosts file. Windows always checks here first... If this is needed on a whole network then things are a little trickier.

Comment: @Big Chris that's what I meant exactly
thanx for the guidance

Comment: Note that it won't "just work", you need a responding server on that IP.

Comment: Related: [How to redirect a URL to a certain IP, as with /etc/hosts?](http://superuser.com/q/461360/150988) and [using /etc/hosts to point url path](http://superuser.com/q/757713/150988).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to set that in your Hosts file.

### Windows

Run Notepad as Administrator, and open

```
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

Add your entry:

```
1.2.3.4 google.com
```

And save.

### Linux

```
nano /etc/hosts
```

### Mac OS X 10.6 - 10.1.8

```
sudo nano /private/etc/hosts
```

Add your entry, save and close the file, then

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```